# Run a Vuejs application using vs code

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vue-router

I am trying to
run an existing project developed by VueJs with asp.net core on vs code.
The application works correctly when I run it with visual studio (IIS Express). But when I try to run it with vs code using this cmd: `npm run serve` , it doesn't work and I got the following error:

[image]

This is the repo of app / structure:

[image]

in ClienApp Folder we have all folders/files for frontend (app.vue is under components folder), screen below:

[image]
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: have you tried from the root source file -> npm run dev

Comment: thanks for your comment. I just tested it, it doesn't work

Comment: darn, so there is no main.js file at all?

Comment: no it doesn't exist

Comment: thats odd. i know our VUE apps have the main.js file under the src folder .... and thats with us using VS Code. :/ not sure what else to offer

Comment: yes.. this is my first experience with, so I don't really know how it should be like. Thank u anyway.

Comment: if you can edit your question with an outline of the folder/file structure someone else may know more

Comment: can you share your repo plz? **I believe more info is need to be provided**

Comment: Looks like there is no `main.js` file exist and in some other file you are referencing this file which causing the issue.

Comment: Done. I added the structure of the app, could you please check again?

Comment: npm i -g npm-check-updates
npm-check-updates -u
npm install

-> check your npm updates?

Comment: @JamieGarcia I checked, dosen't work